# What would happen to my bitcoins?

Tags: backup, bitcoin-wallet-app, wallet-recovery

I have a Bitcoin wallet for android and I would like to know what happens if I back up the wallet and restore it in other phone. Will I be able to use the bitcoins in both devices? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will be able to access the same coins with both devices. You can think about it like if you make a copy of a key to your home, and give it to someone; both people will be able to open the same door.

Comment: Okay! Thank you very much. (I up voted but I still don't have sufficient rating.)

Comment: @hisetip: If this completely answers your question, clicking the check mark will mark it as "accepted".

Comment: Note that the wallet software needs to be designed to handle this.  Some wallets might get confused by transactions that spend their coins that come from somewhere else.

Comment: @NateEldredge Which wallets don't check the utxo to determine a users "balance"? Are there some that just store it in local memory until the device issues a new transaction? Seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Well, for instance, if you have keys in two wallets, you might accidentally double spend.  As I recall from some tests, Bitcoin Core gets confused when this happens, as it refuses to give up on its own transaction even after a conflicting transaction has many confirmations.  You have to `-zapwallettxs` and rescan to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin Wallet uses a deterministic key derivation, so you are able to use both copies in parallel and see the same balances in either.

Comment: Keys/addresses won't diverge. Actually Bitcoin Wallet was the second deterministic wallet, the first being Electrum.

Comment: @AndreasSchildbach: Thank you for the correction!